# ADB shell am start force close error

Tags: android, eclipse, shell, command-line, adb

I want to run my android app from ADB So I run this command

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -W -S -n com.example.myproj/.MainActivity
```

My application starts in emulator but it force closed and the message unfortunately stopped working showed on emulator screen. I try both genymotion and eclipse emulator and got same error.But when I run it from eclipse directly it does not any force close problem.
I should mention that I use ubuntu 14.04 32bit.
Please help me and say what is my mistake and how I can fix it?

ok I use logcat as result I have very long log I just put last part which I can see from command line and seems to relevant to my app

```
D/gralloc (   51): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. 

This may cause memory ordering problems.
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/SurfaceFlinger(   51): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1304732677
E/SurfaceFlinger(   51): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
W/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (266x425) to layer 21005
D/AndroidRuntime( 1133): Shutting down VM
I/ActivityManager(  361): Start proc com.example.myproj for activity com.example.myproj/.MainActivity: pid=1144 uid=10051 gids={50051, 1028, 1015}
D/dalvikvm( 1133): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 15% free 585K/684K, paused 22ms+12ms, total 59ms
D/dalvikvm( 1144): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/Choreographer(  531): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/dalvikvm( 1144): VFY: register1 v4 holds uninitialized ref
W/dalvikvm( 1144): VFY: bad arg 0 (into Ljava/lang/Object;)
W/dalvikvm( 1144): VFY:  rejecting call to Lacteve/symbolic/Util;.write (Ljava/lang/Object;I)V
W/dalvikvm( 1144): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
W/dalvikvm( 1144): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity$1;.<init> (Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity;)V
W/dalvikvm( 1144): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity$1;
D/AndroidRuntime( 1144): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1144): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ae0b90)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144): Process: com.example.myproj, PID: 1144
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144): java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/myproj/MainActivity$1
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at com.example.myproj.MainActivity.dol(MainActivity.java:24)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at com.example.myproj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1144):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  361):   Force finishing activity com.example.myproj/.MainActivity
I/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b40b44d0 ActivityRecord{b40181a0 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t7 f}} appWin=Window{b41a0fe8 u0 Starting com.example.myproj} drawState=4
W/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (800x1280) to layer 21010
W/ActivityManager(  361): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b40181a0 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t7 f}
I/Process ( 1144): Sending signal. PID: 1144 SIG: 9
I/ActivityManager(  361): Process com.example.myproj (pid 1144) has died.
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/InputMethodManagerService(  361): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b417b3a0 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b404fb70
D/AndroidRuntime( 1161): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 1161): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 1161): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm( 1161): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1161): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1161): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1161): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1161): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1161): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
E/memtrack( 1161): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug( 1161): failed to load memtrack module: -2
D/AndroidRuntime( 1161): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
I/ActivityManager(  361): Force stopping com.example.myproj appid=10051 user=0: from pid 1161
I/ActivityManager(  361): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.myproj/.MainActivity} from pid 1161
D/gralloc (   51): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/SurfaceFlinger(   51): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1304732677
E/SurfaceFlinger(   51): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
W/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (266x425) to layer 21005
D/AndroidRuntime( 1161): Shutting down VM
D/dalvikvm( 1161): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 15% free 589K/688K, paused 23ms+32ms, total 71ms
D/dalvikvm( 1172): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/ActivityManager(  361): Start proc com.example.myproj for activity com.example.myproj/.MainActivity: pid=1172 uid=10051 gids={50051, 1028, 1015}
I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/dalvikvm( 1172): VFY: register1 v4 holds uninitialized ref
W/dalvikvm( 1172): VFY: bad arg 0 (into Ljava/lang/Object;)
W/dalvikvm( 1172): VFY:  rejecting call to Lacteve/symbolic/Util;.write (Ljava/lang/Object;I)V
W/dalvikvm( 1172): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
W/dalvikvm( 1172): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity$1;.<init> (Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity;)V
W/dalvikvm( 1172): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity$1;
D/AndroidRuntime( 1172): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1172): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ae0b90)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172): Process: com.example.myproj, PID: 1172
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172): java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/myproj/MainActivity$1
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at com.example.myproj.MainActivity.dol(MainActivity.java:24)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at com.example.myproj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1172):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  361):   Force finishing activity com.example.myproj/.MainActivity
I/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b4186bf8 ActivityRecord{b4186a98 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t8 f}} appWin=Window{b417dc10 u0 Starting com.example.myproj} drawState=4
W/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (800x1280) to layer 21010
W/ActivityManager(  361): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b4186a98 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t8 f}
I/Process ( 1172): Sending signal. PID: 1172 SIG: 9
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
I/dalvikvm(  361): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
I/ActivityManager(  361): Process com.example.myproj (pid 1172) has died.
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
D/LightsService(  361): Excessive delay setting light: 444ms
D/LightsService(  361): Excessive delay setting light: 102ms
W/InputMethodManagerService(  361): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b421b110 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b404fb70
D/dalvikvm(  361): GC_CONCURRENT freed 660K, 10% free 6734K/7468K, paused 7ms+17ms, total 344ms
D/AndroidRuntime( 1189): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 1189): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 1189): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm( 1189): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1189): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1189): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1189): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1189): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1189): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
E/memtrack( 1189): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug( 1189): failed to load memtrack module: -2
D/AndroidRuntime( 1189): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
I/ActivityManager(  361): Force stopping com.example.myproj appid=10051 user=0: from pid 1189
I/ActivityManager(  361): START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.myproj/.MainActivity} from pid 1189
D/gralloc (   51): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/SurfaceFlinger(   51): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1304732677
E/SurfaceFlinger(   51): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
W/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (266x425) to layer 21005
I/ActivityManager(  361): Start proc com.example.myproj for activity com.example.myproj/.MainActivity: pid=1200 uid=10051 gids={50051, 1028, 1015}
D/dalvikvm( 1200): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer(  531): Skipped 84 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/dalvikvm( 1200): VFY: register1 v4 holds uninitialized ref
W/dalvikvm( 1200): VFY: bad arg 0 (into Ljava/lang/Object;)
W/dalvikvm( 1200): VFY:  rejecting call to Lacteve/symbolic/Util;.write (Ljava/lang/Object;I)V
W/dalvikvm( 1200): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
W/dalvikvm( 1200): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity$1;.<init> (Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity;)V
W/dalvikvm( 1200): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity$1;
D/AndroidRuntime( 1200): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1200): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ae0b90)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200): Process: com.example.myproj, PID: 1200
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200): java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/myproj/MainActivity$1
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at com.example.myproj.MainActivity.dol(MainActivity.java:24)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at com.example.myproj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1200):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  361):   Force finishing activity com.example.myproj/.MainActivity
I/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b4083168 ActivityRecord{b3ffc9c8 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t9 f}} appWin=Window{b401a348 u0 Starting com.example.myproj} drawState=4
W/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (800x1280) to layer 21010
W/ActivityManager(  361): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b3ffc9c8 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t9 f}
I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/WindowManager(  361): Starting window AppWindowToken{b41c65a8 token=Token{b4083168 ActivityRecord{b3ffc9c8 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t9}}} timed out
W/ActivityManager(  361): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b3ffc9c8 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t9 f}
D/dalvikvm(  531): GC_CONCURRENT freed 894K, 16% free 5380K/6392K, paused 78ms+17ms, total 167ms
D/dalvikvm(  515): GC_CONCURRENT freed 322K, 12% free 3340K/3780K, paused 6ms+7ms, total 64ms
I/Process ( 1200): Sending signal. PID: 1200 SIG: 9
W/InputMethodManagerService(  361): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b404f558 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b404fb70
I/ActivityManager(  361): Process com.example.myproj (pid 1200) has died.
D/ConnectivityService(  361): Sampling interval elapsed, updating statistics ..
D/ConnectivityService(  361): Done.
D/ConnectivityService(  361): Setting timer for 720seconds
D/dalvikvm(  515): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 14% free 3290K/3792K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 41ms
D/AndroidRuntime( 1240): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 1240): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 1240): CheckJNI is ON
D/dalvikvm( 1240): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1240): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1240): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1240): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 1240): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 1240): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
E/memtrack( 1240): Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
E/android.os.Debug( 1240): failed to load memtrack module: -2
D/AndroidRuntime( 1240): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
I/ActivityManager(  361): Force stopping com.example.myproj appid=10051 user=0: from pid 1240
I/ActivityManager(  361): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=logcat cmp=com.example.myproj/.MainActivity} from pid 1240
D/gralloc (   51): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/SurfaceFlinger(   51): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 1304732677
E/SurfaceFlinger(   51): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
E/libEGL  (   51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
W/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (266x425) to layer 21005
I/ActivityManager(  361): Start proc com.example.myproj for activity com.example.myproj/.MainActivity: pid=1251 uid=10051 gids={50051, 1028, 1015}
D/dalvikvm( 1251): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/dalvikvm( 1251): VFY: register1 v4 holds uninitialized ref
W/dalvikvm( 1251): VFY: bad arg 0 (into Ljava/lang/Object;)
W/dalvikvm( 1251): VFY:  rejecting call to Lacteve/symbolic/Util;.write (Ljava/lang/Object;I)V
W/dalvikvm( 1251): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
W/dalvikvm( 1251): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity$1;.<init> (Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity;)V
W/dalvikvm( 1251): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/myproj/MainActivity$1;
D/AndroidRuntime( 1251): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1251): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ae0b90)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251): Process: com.example.myproj, PID: 1251
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251): java.lang.VerifyError: com/example/myproj/MainActivity$1
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at com.example.myproj.MainActivity.dol(MainActivity.java:24)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at com.example.myproj.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1251):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  361):   Force finishing activity com.example.myproj/.MainActivity
I/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b41deb30 ActivityRecord{b4232990 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t10 f}} appWin=Window{b423e4b0 u0 Starting com.example.myproj} drawState=4
W/WindowManager(  361): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (800x1280) to layer 21010
D/dalvikvm(  361): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1117K, 16% free 6529K/7720K, paused 16ms+34ms, total 347ms
W/ActivityManager(  361): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b4232990 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t10 f}
I/Choreographer(  531): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/LightsService(  361): Excessive delay setting light: 82ms
D/LightsService(  361): Excessive delay setting light: 426ms
I/Choreographer(  361): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/LightsService(  361): Excessive delay setting light: 1681ms
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
E/SoundPool(  361): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
W/AudioService(  361): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
I/Process ( 1251): Sending signal. PID: 1251 SIG: 9
D/LightsService(  361): Excessive delay setting light: 320ms
D/LightsService(  361): Excessive delay setting light: 190ms
D/LightsService(  361): Excessive delay setting light: 73ms
I/ActivityManager(  361): Process com.example.myproj (pid 1251) has died.
W/InputMethodManagerService(  361): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b3f8b170 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b404fb70
E/WindowManager(  361): Starting window AppWindowToken{b4233820 token=Token{b41deb30 ActivityRecord{b4232990 u0 com.example.myproj/.MainActivity t10}}} timed out
I/ActivityManager(  361): Killing 564:com.android.printspooler/u0a38 (adj 15): empty for 1807s
I/ProcessStatsService(  361): Prepared write state in 25ms
I/ProcessStatsService(  361): Prepared write state in 16ms
```

Comment: [logcat](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) has its own docs. When running from Eclipse, you'll most likely use a different command to start the activity. That might make the difference.

Comment: do you get the "stopped working" message when you start your activity with `am start` but without `-W -S` flags?

Comment: Yes,I got "stopped working message" when I start main activity with am command and with -W and -S flag.